# QT Addin for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I have some problems getting the QT Addin for Visual Studio to work correctly.

What I did (running Windows 8.1 Pro):

- I installed Visual Studio 2013
- I installed QT (using qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64-5.3.1.exe)
- I downloaded the QT VS addin (qt-vs-addin-1.2.3-opensource.exe) and installed it...

What I think does not work correctly:

- Visual Studio does not show the entry "QT" in the main menu bar
- Under File->New->Project is no entry to select a QT Project

I added a path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Digia\Qt5VSAddin\12.0) to the addin search paths. After that the entry "QT" in the main menu bar showed up.

I configured the qt version (QT->QT options):

```
Name          Path
msvc2013_64   C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64
```

Since I cannot create a QT Project within VS, I created one with QTCreator and opened the existing one in VS. Unfortunately it does not work either:

```
Fehler  1   error LNK1117: Syntaxfehler in Option  
"SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS@QMAKE_SUBSYSTEM_SUFFIX@".    C:\proj\qt-test\LINK    qt-test
```

EDIT: There is now a [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-381). The whole setup works for me, if I run VS with admin privileges, as described in the bugreport.

Well, then I assume this is closed?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but which version of VS2013 do you use?

Comment: Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2

Comment: That's not what I meant. Express, Desktop, Professional, Premium, Test, Ultimate? E.g. not all VS2013 versions can deploy C++. If indeed it works with admin privileges, that's not your worry, though.

Comment: Oh, its Visual Studio Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error, you must go to **Project Properties -> Link -> Command line**.

You then see the string:
`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS%40QMAKE_SUBSYSTEM_SUFFIX%40`
Replace it by:
`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`

---

Source : [QtCenter](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59315-Qt5-Visual-Studio-2013-build-error-SUBSYSTEM-WINDOWS-QMAKE_SUBSYSTEM_SUFFIX)